# View my previous location with leaflet API

Tags: javascript, json, openstreetmap

I just start using Leaflet JS to build an interactive map viewer that can track movement of multiple devices. I'm using JSON data to set latitude and longitude for every marker.

The JSON data look like this:

```
var Point = [
{

   "id": 1,
   "name": "A",
   "LastUpdate": [36.8474448, 10.2793222],
   "position": [36.8479648, 10.2793332]
},{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "B",
   "LastUpdate": [36.8791079, 10.2656109],
   "position":[ 36.8791039, 10.2656209]
},{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "C",
   "LastUpdate": [36.9922641, 10.1255150],
   "position": [36.9922751, 10.1255164]
}
];
```

The data contain position information from 3 devices(first it's static).
I already succeed to locate my mac on the map, but I want to get a list of my last positions on the map.
Here my JS code is like (to locate my mac):

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([36.8479648, 10.2793332], 10);map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 10,watch: true});
```

Comment: You need to dispaly only LastUpdate points ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This all are last points in array Point or only one point need to show?

Comment: with those points i just tried static view, but now i need to know my previous location(historic)

Comment: You need to take that point from point array and place on your view based on some button click like previous location button.By this way you can achiive this task

Comment: and if i want to detect my previous point?

Comment: For that you need to manage index for current position let say your current position is 5 then your index is 5 after that you need to decrement it by 1 and get that index LastUpdate point and place that on map.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the [Leaflet History](https://github.com/cscott530/leaflet-history) plugin.